# PresentViewController only working once

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, presentviewcontroller

I'm a bit dazzled here. And I do think it might be something stupid, but here it goes.

I'm using ABPadLockScreen to set a password and it works just fine when I open the app first time and if the app is closed (terminated) and reopened, but if I just go home and return to it I get the following warning

```
Warning: Attempt to present <ABPadLockScreenViewController: 0x7fdc70f1d5a0> on <ViewController: 0x7fdc70f18e00> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Just for more information here is the code that triggers it, it's inside the viewDidAppear

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

if (!self.pin && delegate.terminated) {
    //        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Pin" message:@"Please Set a pin before trying to unlock" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    //return;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
} else if (!self.isPin && !delegate.terminated) {

    ABPadLockScreenViewController *lockScreen = [[ABPadLockScreenViewController alloc] initWithDelegate:self complexPin:YES];
    [lockScreen setAllowedAttempts:3];

    lockScreen.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    lockScreen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

    [self presentViewController:lockScreen animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

If you're wondering about the delegate, it was so the Password Screen would show up when the app was simply closed and reopened and that's when the warning occurs.

Also, if I simply switch from one view to another, the damn thing shows up again.

Thanks in advance